# Why does Blender convert ALL of the metaballs to mesh and not only the selected object?

Tags: modeling, metaballs

Why does Blender convert ALL of the metaballs in the scene to mesh and not only the selected object?

First of all, you can't use modifiers on them. This means you can't treat them as mesh and decimate etc. after you reach your favorite metaball configuration. Which doesn't make any sense at all.

And as a final touch, you can't even convert a single metaball object to mesh because Blender will convert ALL the metaball objects to mesh, leaving you n chance to have a "backup" metaball object in case you need to change something.

Is there a reason for these limitations?

Comment: Metaballs are organized in families (see https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/metas/editing.html#object-families) and all family elements interact, so they are linked when transformed to mesh.

Comment: OK, and as you can see if you have ever worked with them, this is not friendly at all, for the reasons explained in the OP. They are ok for playing around, but for productivity, they are a real pain, and it's not even the expected behavior: when I duplicate an object, I expect it to be a whole new object apart, with no link with the original one. If I want to duplicate the metaballs of the original one, I will select them and duplicate. This could be treated in so many different ways, I wonder why they have put up these limitations and incoherencies with the standard Blender behavior.

Comment: maybe it is hard to determinate how to cut the "to mesh conversion" for one metaball only? do you have some rules for that?

Comment: "*I wonder why they have put up these limitations and incoherencies with the standard Blender behavior.*" Blender developers don't sit all day twirling their mustaches and thinking how they are going to screw artists next or limit their creativity out of pure spite. Most issues in Blender rise from lack of resources, or ability to do better, or a simply the product of age and technical limitations of their time.

Comment: Why my question has been downvoted?

Comment: @lemon I think it would be quite easy: as written, you can identify a family of metaballs when they are in the same object. They are ALREADY split in the hierarchy.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos you don't need to be so bitter about my question or comment. Maybe be more relaxed would be a good thing. I'm not disregarding the great work that the incredible community minds do on Blender. It just comes to me as strange that this particular thing seems incomplete and I can't understand why it has been organized this way. Can I have a doubt? Have you ever had a doubt and asked info about it? Calm down, dude.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Metaballs are organized in families (see [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/metas/editing.html#object-families)) and all family elements interact, so they are linked when transformed to mesh.

If you want to convert to mesh one single metaball, how to determinate where it ends?

As this is not determined, Blender's choice is to convert them all (and this is a coherent choice).

For other points you mentioned in comment (incoherencies, etc.) I cannot answer... this is the way it is (where to cut a single metaball, etc.).

Comment: You can identify a metaball object. They are ALREADY split in the hierarchy. Try to create one metaball object, then another. Why unify them into a single family??? That's why the behavior in this case is unexpected: if I convert an object, why propagate the conversion to OTHER metaball objects? And this is the first time I hear about "families"...

Comment: @PolyMad, I don't know more than the doc about that. Have you read the link I've provided in the answer above?

Comment: Having just read that article, I tried renaming a group of backed-up metaballs (making sure, as per the documentation, to have the name before the period all consistant). After doing that and selecting the original and converting it to mesh, I now have a merged group of metaballs as a mesh, and a backup group of metaballs in their original state.